# How to reproduce a KeyboardEvent

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to design a script to manipulate Google Talk chat boxes. Currently my working code is to select the text box via `document.get...` and the default class name, and I have to get a `KeyboardEvent` manually by hijacking `window.onKeyDown`. The only dependency of my code is that I have this KeyboardEvent:

```
altGraphKey: false,
altKey: false,
bubbles: true,
cancelBubble: false,
cancelable: true,
charCode: 0,
clipboardData: undefined,
ctrlKey: false,
currentTarget: null,
defaultPrevented: true,
detail: 0,
eventPhase: 0,
keyCode: 13,
keyIdentifier: "Enter",
keyLocation: 0,
layerX: 0,
layerY: 0,
location: 0,
metaKey: false,
pageX: 0,
pageY: 0,
repeat: false,
returnValue: false,
shiftKey: false,
srcElement: document.getElementsByClassName("ad3")[0],
target: document.getElementsByClassName("ad3")[0],
timeStamp: 1396471663202,
type: "keydown",
view: Window,
which: 13,
__proto__: KeyboardEvent
```

In this object, `view` is something strange. I have tried to copy the `Window` object without avail into a field-by-field reproduced `KeyboardEvent`, whose `view` is `null`.

How can I duplicate such a `KeyboardEvent`? I can't serialize it either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345454/how-can-i-generate-a-keypress-event-in-safari-with-javascript

Comment: @zshooter Actually, that does not work, as that simply puts text. I have to trigger the event of a keyboard LF press. Putting a `\n` doesn't work.