# Simulate JavaScript Keypress on Text Field (Safari)

Tags: javascript, safari, keypress

I`m trying to simulate a keypress event in a text field via javascript but seems that nothing works on Safari. I can see that some examples works at document level but none of them works with my text field.

Could please someone help-me? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";

keyboardEvent[initMethod](
               "keypress", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                true, // bubbles
                true, // cancelable
                window, // viewArg: should be window
                false, // ctrlKeyArg
                false, // altKeyArg
                false, // shiftKeyArg
                false, // metaKeyArg
                40, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
document.getElementById('mytextbox').dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

Obs: the textInput event don't work in my scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a keypress event in Safari with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345454/how-can-i-generate-a-keypress-event-in-safari-with-javascript)

Comment: Actually no, because the solution presented in this link don't produces a keypress event, but a textInput event, which don't work in my scenario. But thanks anyway.