# Chrome Extension Trigger Keydown JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension which needs to be able to trigger keydown events at the document level of the target page. The target page has an event listener which uses javascript like:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {…});
```

My manifest.json is as follows:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Title",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Testing",
    "icons": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Title"
    },

    "author": "James McLaughlin",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery.js", "event.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

And my event.js:

```
function injectedMethod (tab, method, callback) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'jquery.js'}, function() {});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'inject.js'}, function() {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {method: method}, callback);
    });
}

function run (tab) {
    injectedMethod(tab, 'run', function (response) {
        return true;
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(run);
```

And my inject.js (I used one of the methods of JS injection available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) because it seemed applicable:

```
var injected = injected || (function(){

    var methods = {};

    methods.run = function () {
    injectScript(function () {
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 40;
        $(document).trigger(e);
    });
    }

    function injectScript(func) {
        var actualCode = '(' + func + ')();';
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.textContent = actualCode;
        (document.body||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
        //script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
    }

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        $('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>').appendTo('head');
        var data = {};

        if (methods.hasOwnProperty(request.method))
        data = methods[request.method]();

        sendResponse({data:data});
        return true;
    });

    return true;
})();
```

However, when I push the chrome extension, the target page does not respond to the keydown event. This got me thinking that perhaps a jQuery-generated event cannot trigger a pure JS listener. To test this theory, I put the following in an HTML file and ran it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    //listener one
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        alert(event.which);
    });

    //listener two
    $(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
        alert(event.which);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 40;
        $(document).trigger(e);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I ran the above html file, only the jQuery event listener was fired. When I commented out the jQuery listener, nothing happened. Furthermore, when I commented out the JS listener and uncommented the JS listener, the jQuery event listener fired without problem.

Since the jQuery keydown did not appear to fire the pure JS listener in either case, I tried to trigger the keydown with pure JS:

```
    var pressEvent = document.createEvent ('KeyboardEvent');
    pressEvent.initKeyEvent ('keydown', true, true, window, true, false, false, false, 65, 0);
    document.dispatchEvent (pressEvent);
```

However, that generates an "undefined is not a function" on the "initKeyEvent".

I also tried the suggestion available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401547/js-trigger-keydown-event), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152932/chrome-extension-how-to-send-keydown-event-to-pages-input) (but that one did not specify a which or keyCode, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714422/jquery-keydown-trigger-not-working) (but again no keyCode or which),

How can I trigger a pure JS keydown listener from a Chrome extension?

Thank you

Comment: Does pieces work as general document ? i.e.g., If try `event` pieces as `js` without implementing within `extension`, does `keydown` `event` work ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 I'm sorry; what is it exactly you want me to try? I am not quite sure what that means.

Comment: Do the pieces work at general web page (`document`) ? Without trying to incorporate with an `extension` ? Does the piece as whole work at general `html` document, with `jquery` loaded at document ?

Comment: @guest271314 Ah. Now I think I understand. I think I may have already addressed that (please see the HTML document above right after I said "I put the following in an HTML file and ran it:". Basically, the jQuery-generated keydown triggered only the jQuery-based keydown listener and not the actual JS listener. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (pattern)

manifest.json

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
```

js (modified `jquery-1.10-2.min-chromium-ext.js`)

```
// if `jquery` not in `window`, utilize `jquery-1.10-2.min-chromium-ext.js`
if (!window.jQuery) {
// `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`
};
// _eof_
```

js (background.js)

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {   
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "jquery-1.10.2.min-chromium-ext.js"}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "chromium-extension.js"})
  });   
});
```

js (chromium-extension.js)

```
    $(function() {        
      if (window.jQuery) {          
        $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
          alert(e.which)
        })       
      };        
    });
```

Resources https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples‎

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked

Comment: Please edit your answer. No need for all the licenses in the code here (you linked to the full one) and your list is barely readable.

Comment: @Xan Removed license. Not certain about list ? Need to adjust formatting ? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you really need to write it out step by step? URL to the zip, saying to load it as unpacked extension with a link to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked should be much more readable. The person asking the question seems reasonable

Comment: Much better, upvoted, now question is whether it will help @cryptopi