# Auto arrow (right) key press event?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

Is it possible to create an auto key press event? I want to flip a book once automatically after refreshing the site?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 39 });// right arrow key
    $(document).trigger(e);
});
```

References:

- [JS trigger keydown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401547/js-trigger-keydown-event)
- [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)
- [Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery)

Comment: thank's for the fast reply! unfortunately it doesn't work... here is the link: [link](http://goo.gl/RsBTDh) Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You probably just need to trigger the event on the specific element that’s listening for it. Will take a look at your site.

Comment: @jkr137 Just updated my answer for your specific case. Worked for me in the browser console.

Comment: wow! thanks for your fast answer! it works, but is it possible to put a delay on it? I tried something but it doesn't work :) `$(document).delay (1000).ready(function() {
    var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 39 });// right arrow key
    $(document).trigger(e);`

Comment: Glad that worked! To add a delay, you’ll need to use `window.setTimeout()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

```
$(window).load(function()  {
    var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 39 });// right arrow key
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).trigger(e);
             }, 1000);
});
```

Many thanks!