# React Js Text input cursor position for mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to set position of the cursor at end of the text. I can do that, no issues there.
Problem is in `mozilla`. It works fine for short text. In case of long text I don't know if the cursor is being placed at the end or not. Let's assume it does cuz it works fine for short text.
On `google chrome` if there is long text the cursor is placed at the end when onFocus is called and text sort of scrolls towards left so that end of the text is visible with the cursor.

Now, that scrolling thing should happen on `mozilla` but it doesn't. I need help.

`Mozilla` example:

[image: mozilla example]

Google chrome example: 
[image: chrome example]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Comment: @AmarSingh I'm first haha

Comment: As I said placing cursor at end is not the problem.

Comment: @PrabhJot https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416714/5336818 I tested this answer on mozilla , text scrolls to left and shows the cursor at the end. Test it.

Comment: @seunggabi if the text is long it should also scroll the text

Comment: @PrabhJot okay I understand, I'm sorry misunderstand..

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger `onfoucs callback` 
If you use jQuery

```js
$('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
    var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 39 }); // right arrow key
    $(this).trigger(e);
});
```

reference: [Auto arrow (right) key press event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370794/auto-arrow-right-key-press-event)